# flutter: trying to send a file with an Arabic name to the api

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to send a file with an Arabic name to the api, but it is saved in the api with an encrypted name, knowing that the problem is only with the Arabic names. I thought that the problem was with the api itself, but when I tested the api on the postman it was accepting files with Arabic names, the problem is in the code and I don’t know what is the problem. please help.

[image: description]

Comment: You should probably add the bit of code you use to send the file to the API. This looks like an encoding issue to me

Comment: Have you tried to encode it as utf8 before sending : var myDataString = utf8.encode(string);